# Binary to Decimal number converter in JAVA?

Tags: java

What is the problem with my code.
It prints 1 for any value of input.

```
package Assign;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class Assignment {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = s.nextInt();
    int x = 1;
    int sum = 1, i = 0;

    while (num > 0) {
        x = num % 10;
        if (x == 1) {
            sum = sum + (2 * i);
        }
        num = num / 10;
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```

Comment: When you debugged this code, what exactly did you see that didn't make sense?

Comment: Look at `x`. You save the value of an operation in it, but then never save the value of that operation. Start there.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) You need to add 2^i to sum, not 2*i

2) Sum starts at 1 instead of 0, meaning the answer will always be 1 more than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to develop the algorithm yourself, here is a shorter way to do it:

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(num), 2));
```

Comment: You should include more context/explanation for your code - please see [answer].

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this.

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(binaryString,2));
```

Comment: You should include more context/explanation - please see [answer].

Comment: A good java programmer can understand it easily.

Answer (score 0):

In the program the only case where the variable sum is getting modified when ***(num > 0)*** is in the if block. 
Considering the if block

```
if (x == 1) {
   sum = sum + (2 * i);
}
```

since the variable ***i = 0***.

```
sum = sum + (2 * i);
```

evaluates to

```
sum = sum + (2 * 0);
sum = sum + 0;
sum = sum;
```

since the variable ***sum = 1***, the output is always 1.

Considering the other possibility, when ***(num <= 0)*** where while loop is skipped, since ***sum = 1***, the output is 1.

For Binary to Decimal number converter in Java check out

http://www.java2novice.com/java-interview-programs/binary-to-decimal/